# Is there any way to add a button to a canvas using javafx

Tags: java

Okay so I am trying to make a simple game so I used a canvas to draw the characters and now I need to add a button over this canvas to make the characters move and I can't find a way to do this in javaFX

Comment: Perhaps you could use a `BorderPane` and set the canvas as the center component and the button as the bottom component.

Comment: it just adds the button under the canvas I want to put it above it

Comment: So use method `setTop()` of class `BorderPane` and the button will be above the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your canvas into an AnchorPane and then you can add a Button to that too which will be shown on top of the canvas then. With the anchors you can place the button exactly where you want to have it.